# showing a message in openerp login page

Tags: odoo

How to show a message in openerp login page? I need to show a message similar to 'invalid username or password' but this should not fade and it should be in the login page without any clicks. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding following  in the   instance.web.Login start function 
"""this.show_error(_t("Your Message "));""""